# Backbone history do not start

Tags: backbone.js, history

i'm quite a newbie on Backbone, and this is driving me crazy:
I'm using backbone and Marionette.
Here is some code sample to begin :

```
var Backbone    = require('backbone'),
    Marionette  = require('backbone.marionette'),
    FastClick   = require('fastclick');

var MainModule      = require('./modules/main'),
    HomeModule      = require('./modules/home');

var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.vent.on('ready', function(e) {
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true, // Use HTML5 history if available
        hashChange: false, // or refresh pages if it isnt supported natively
        root: '/',
    })
});
```

and in my /module/home/index.js :

```
module.exports = function HomeModule(Module, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

// Register Sub modules
App.module('Home', LayoutModule);
App.module('Home', WallModule);

Module.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        '/': 'home',
        'social-wall': 'socialwall'
    }
});

var controller = {
    home: function() {
        App.mainRegion.show(new Module.Layout());
    },

    socialwall: function() {
        controller.home();
        App.mainRegion.currentView.scrollToSocialWall();
    }
};

App.addInitializer(function() {
    new Module.Router({ controller: controller });
});
};
```

The problem is that Backbone.history.start do not trigger anything. If i understand the code correctly, the history.start() should find the '/' route in the HomeModule and trigger the associated function... Am I wrong??
Why is this not working?????

In advance, thanks

Comment: What url are you accessing?

Comment: Who is triggering `app.vent.on('ready'` thingy..?

Comment: the 'ready' event is triggered by app.start() (marionette framework), later in the main.js.
And i'm accessing localhost/. Maybe it's more a deployment error. Backbone seems to be included twice by my gulp-browserify script. I'm totally lost.....

Comment: I'm not familar with Backbone Marionette but [according to the documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.2/marionette.application.html#getting-started), a *`start`* event is triggered on `app` itself. Which version of Marionette are you using? Please add the version and the tag [tag:marionette.js] to your post by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!
as i said in the comment, it was a deployment error. The error was a bad package.json file on a npm install.
Tip to front-devs : when u're making a npm package to install and deploy a Marionette project, be sure to include Backbone first, and with an explicit version... including only Marionette will cause npm to install Backbone twice (on project root and in marionette modules), and this is a source of big troubles...